# How to make CellTable Header always on top in ScrollPanel in GWT

Tags: gwt

Here is my code.

```java
VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
HorizontalPanel cellTablePanel = new HorizontalPanel();
ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
CellTable table = new CellTable();

scrollPanel.add(table);
cellTablePanel.add(scrollPanel);
mainPanel.add(cellTablePanel);
```

I want the heading of the table to be permanently on top and the data to be scrollable. Right now as I scroll down the table the heading also gets scrolled down and I am not able to see the heading. As I scroll up back again then only I am able to see the heading. So is there any way so that I can have the header fixed.

**Note:** I  have to use CellTable only.I cannot use any other widget.

Comment: Use a dataGrid instead: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html

Comment: Use DataGrid instead of celltable which will behave same as celltable and header,footer are fixed

Comment: I cannot use a datagrid, i have a customised celltable that i have used throughout my project. So I have to use Celltable only. What is the possible way to do this using Celltable itself?

Comment: There is a solution implemented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073624/a-gwt-celltable-with-frozen-header-and-initial-column?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use DataGrid, you can put it in a DockPanel with the HTML representing your header. It will be non-resizable and non-sortable. I did it to a CellList because I do not use CellTables (not mobile-friendly). However at that point you are making a custom widget (Composite), so you can as well refactor it into a DataGrid like others suggested. Go through refactoring pain once and enjoy the clean design forever.

Answer (score 0):

Take a moment and read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850380/1018903)

You can do the same using a [Window.addWindowScrollHandler()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#addWindowScrollHandler(com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.ScrollHandler)). Implement the same logic and then set the column headers style to a fixed position or not.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
get current header position
get current scroll position
if header is above current scroll then:
    set style to fix the header at the top
else:
    set style to regular position
```